# C# For Loop To ListBox variable not multiplying

Tags: c#, loops, listbox

I am making a c# program that converts MPH + hours traveled into distance then display it in the list box like this.

- After 0 hours your distance is 20 miles.
- After 1 hours your distance is 30 miles.
- After 2 hours your distance is 40  miles.

However when I run my program it looks more like this

- After 0 hours your distance is 20 miles.
- After 1 hours your distance is 20 miles.
- After 2 hours your distance is 20 miles.

As you can see my miles is not multiplying, my code is as follows,

```
        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double MPH;
        double hourstraveled;
        double distance;
        MPH = double.Parse(vehicleSpeedTextBox.Text);
        hourstraveled = double.Parse(hoursTraveledTextBox.Text);
        distance = MPH * hourstraveled;
        int count;
        for (count = 0; count <= hourstraveled; count++)
        displayListBox.Items.Add("After" + count + "Hours traveled you have gone" + distance + "Miles");


    }
```

Comment: You don't change `distance` inside the loop. It'll keep the value it has outside it. If you want to change it then change it inside the loop. It also doesn't depend on the loop variable in any way.

Comment: You also need to add spaces.  It would read "AfterXHours...goneYMiles".

Comment: When you assign to distance, it's value is not going to be recalculated whenever you access it. You have to recalculate it every time count changes (currently it's not even using count).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate the `distance` value once:

```
distance = MPH * hourstraveled;
```

And you use it in each iteration of your loop:

```
for (count = 0; count <= hourstraveled; count++)
    displayListBox.Items.Add("After" + count + "Hours traveled you have gone" + distance + "Miles");
```

But you never re-calculate it.  So the value will never change from that initial calculated value.

Since the value is dynamic and dependent on the `count` value, you don't even need a variable at all.  Just calculate it on the fly.  You don't even need `hourstraveled` in the calculation.  Maybe something like this?:

```
for (count = 0; count <= hourstraveled; count++)
    displayListBox.Items.Add("After " + count + " Hours traveled you have gone " + ((count + 1) * MPH) + " Miles");
```

Though, wouldn't the distance after 0 hours be 0 miles?:

```
for (count = 0; count <= hourstraveled; count++)
    displayListBox.Items.Add("After " + count + " Hours traveled you have gone " + (count * MPH) + " Miles");
```